# How to stop unused dying hard drive from clicking

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, hardware-failure, hard-drive-failure

Since a week ago I have been getting a warning on start-up that my hard-drive is about to fail. It also makes an extremely annoying clicking sound. I have tried disabling it in device manager but when I restart it is active again. In disk management I removed the volume and formated the disk.

Any ideas how to stop this horrific clicking that is driving me insane without opening the laptop and disconnecting the power?

Comment: Eventually it will either grind to a halt or burst into flames… why not disconnect it?

Comment: It is a laptop and I don't trust myself to open it.

Answer (score 1):

The drive has a severe hardware error and the clicking cannot be solved by software. You said it is unused, so simply remove it and put it aside (recycle). You may need a person / friend to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the **BIOS** before to start the OS and disable that warning.

Comment: Thanks. I don't mind the warning. It is the clicking that bothers me.

Comment: The hard drive will be clicking as long as it has power. You really have no choice other than to disconnect the HDD physically (remove it)